# Using the same script for training and serving (Estimator + hub)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-hub

I want to use hub at training and serving, but I am getting a little confused how to do it on the same graph. Namely I have something like

```
def build_graph(..., mode, ...):
    tags_and_args= ... # one for training, one for serving
    if mode == 'training':
        hub.create_module_spec(module_fn, tags_and_args=tags_and_args)
        module_output = hub.Module(...)
        hub.register_module_for_export(module_fn, tags_and_args=tags_and_args)

        loss, output = ...

    else:
        module_output = hub.Module(XXX)
```

should I reload the module from disk? Therefore `XXX` will be the path where i saved it before. Or is it somehow saved as a graph object in memory?

I will call my code as

```
estimator.train(...)
exporter = hub.LatestModuleExporter(...)
exporter.export(...)
esimator.export_savedmodel(...)  # for serving
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hub.Module in the model_fn of an Estimator without ever exporting it. At the start of Estimator.train(), the module's variables will be initialized from their pre-trained values (much like other variables are initialized randomly). After that, the module's variables behave much like the other variables of your model - they are part of the model's checkpoint, and restored from there for evaluation, resumed training, or export to a SavedModel for serving, like any other variable.

Exporting a hub.Module is only needed in case you want to create a new version of the module (with the weights updated from your training) available to yet another, separate Estimator.